# Waiting for the inline button to be pressed from user in a loop from the aiogram 3.4

Tags: aiogram

I am writing a request handler in a telegram bot. I am having difficulty processing the waiting for pressing the inline button, can you tell me if this can be implemented? I have a ticket monitoring start handler, get them in json, then process each ticket in the list.

```
class MonitoringStatus(StatesGroup):
    monitoring_active = State()
    monitoring_pending = State()
    waiting_for_ticket_action = State()
```

```
def get_ticket_keyboard():
    builder = InlineKeyboardBuilder()
    builder.add(
        InlineKeyboardButton(
        text="assign",
        callback_data="assign"),
        InlineKeyboardButton(
            text="resolve",
            callback_data="resolve"),
    )

    return builder.as_markup()
```

```
@router.message(None or MonitoringStatus.monitoring_pending, F.text == 'Start Monitoring')
async def start_monitoring(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.set_state(MonitoringStatus.monitoring_active)
    await state.update_data(is_monitoring_active=True)
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    await message.answer('Monitoring started')

    while True:
        is_monitoring_active = data.get('is_monitoring_active', False)  
        if not is_monitoring_active:
            break

        tickets = await fetch_tickets_from_file()

        for ticket in tickets:
            await message.answer(f'Ticket: {ticket["ticket_number"]}\n'
                                 f'Reporter: {ticket["reporter"]}\n'
                                 f'Description: {ticket["description"]}',
                                 reply_markup=get_ticket_keyboard())

            await MonitoringStatus.waiting_for_ticket_action.set()

        await asyncio.sleep(10)
```

And I get an error
AttributeError: 'State' object has no attribute 'set'.

If I don't use the set() function, all requests from "tickets" in cycle instantly leave messages in telegram, but I need to process each ticket sequentially.

UPD
I did a status check in an infinite loop and it works for me. But I don't know how right it is.

```
for ticket in tickets:
...
    while True:
        updated_state = await state.get_state()
        if updated_state != current_state:
            break
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
```